# How to bind a existing column of DataGridView with datetimepicker control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have gone through many articles but everyone redirects to 
[How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx/).

But the problem lies here is that I dont want to add new column to my DataGridView which the article says to do it.I am having a DataGridView which is filled through the DataSource property of Grid.The data is coming from the database and filling the Dataset which indirectly fills the DataGridView.

So would like to ask how to add datetimepicker to my existing column of datagrid using the above article.So far I have created three classes namely CalendarColumn.cs, CalendarCells.cs and CalendarEditingControl.cs.

Also would like to ask about the NULL values the column has.Will the Null values will be handled by the classes or do we have to add some code?

The Output m getting is something like this---

[image: Not Expected]

and I want that extra column(Unnamed) not to appear in the Grid and show only the DateOfBirth column with DTP control as shown below--

[image: Expected]

Any links or articles would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean DateTimepicker should be available when you are using `AutoGenerateColumns=true` ?

Comment: No @V4Vendetta m not setting AutoGenerateColumns=true.I want to have a column with dtp control.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: have a look at the edited part..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article, I hope it will be useful: [DataGridViewExtension](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewExtension.aspx).